# trying to use an outer query on already working inner query sql but having error 1064

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

need help to understand what's happening here as when I am trying to use an outer query on
already working inner query which is as

> inner query

```
SELECT DISTINCT (department_id) FROM `departments` ORDER BY department_id ASC;
```

which produces a list of department id's however when I enclose this within an outer query to count the number of department ids like

> with outer query

```
SELECT COUNT(department_id) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT (department_id)  FROM `departments` ORDER BY department_id ASC;)
```

then it gives error as

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' at line 2

I am ushing phpmyadmin ,thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like the `;` is out of place: `ASC;)` => `ASC);` ?

Comment: tried that still does not work. I also tried ASC ; ) ;

Answer (score 1):

The subquery should not have a semicolon, but it should have an alias:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(department_id)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT department_id
    FROM departments
    ORDER BY department_id
) t;
```

Note that using `ORDER BY` in the subquery without `LIMIT` is fairly meaningless.  Also, you could instead just have done a single level distinct count query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT department_id)
FROM departments;
```